# Create a cleaner way to set up a struct with multiple inits?

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I currently have a struct with multiple ways to initialize it.  Currently it works, I'm just wondering if there is a cleaner way of creating the struct? Here it is:

```
    struct Destination {
    var name: String? = "Unkown"
    var waypoint: JMapWaypoint?

    init(destination: JMapDestination) {
        self.name = destination.name
        self.waypoint = destination.waypoints?.first
    }


    init (waypoint: JMapWaypoint) {
        self.waypoint = waypoint
        self.name = "Shared Location"

    }


    init(point: CGPoint, name: String, mapController: JMapController){
        self.name = name
        let pointToJMapPoint = JMapPoint.init(x: Float(point.x),
                                                  y: Float(point.y),
                                                  z: Float(mapController.userLocation.mapId))


        self.waypoint = mapController.getNearestWaypoint(with: pointToJMapPoint ?? JMapPoint())
    }
}
```

Comment: For the last one, you could create a destination and pass that to `init(destination: )`. BTW, are `currentDestination` and `currentMapController` names of structs or classes? In that case they should be capitalized.

Comment: what is `mapController` and where are you getting it from?

Comment: @IchBinStudenten whoops, its not mapController, its positionController.

Comment: `currentDestination` and `mapPoint` are type names? They should be upper camel case.

Comment: `"Unknown"` is a misplaced responsibility. It's not the job for an unnamed destination to invent its own name. Use `nil` instead.

Comment: This code is very confusing; it's not clear why `pointToMapPoint` can be optional among many other things. Can you post a version of this that will compile. It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve. Much of the messiness is that you've made too many things optional. Is `name` really Optional? (Is an empty name really different than no name? This is particularly strange when coupled with the "Unknown" default.) It seems that `waypoint` can really be Optional, but is that a good thing for the caller or could you simplify things by requiring it?

Comment: `wayPoint` vs `waypoint`, be consistent.

Comment: @RobNapier I (for one) like optional strings. Empty strings can silently slip by, whereas Optional strings force you to handle them. `optString ?? "Unknown!"` is nicer than `string.isEmpty ? "Unknown" : string` (I know that can be hid away in a method like `replacingBlank(with:)`, but still

Comment: Hold up, there's both a `mapPoint` type (on which you call `mapPoint.init(x:y:z:)`, *and* a `MapPoint` (struct or function, can't tell)? Don't do that.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica   I edited the post, it should be more consistent now

Comment: Optional String makes sense if nil should be replaced with "Unknown" but "" should be left as an empty string. If that is the meaning, then that's fine, and you have two different values with distinct behaviors. If it is not the meaning, and you ever feel the need for either an `.emptyOrNil()` method or you ever write `?? ""`, then you almost certainly did not mean Optional String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what *cleaner* means in your understanding. There are a lot of ways to reduce `init`s in your code. You can give them a default values e.g., or create some other *struct* named **DestinationParams** that will include all params you need.

```
struct Destination {
    private (set) var name: String
    private (set) var waypoint: JMapWaypoint?

    init(destination: JMapDestination? = nil) {
        self.init(name: destination?.name ?? "Shared Location",
                  waypoint: destination?.waypoints?.first)
    }

    init(name: String, point: JMapPoint? = JMapPoint(), mapController: JMapController) {
        let waypoint = mapController.getNearestWaypoint(with: point)
        self.init(name: name,
                  waypoint: waypoint)
    }

    private init(name: String, waypoint: JMapWaypoint?) {
        self.waypoint = waypoint
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

or, you can modify it by moving all computation outside of `init` like this:

```
...
let pointToJMapPoint = JMapPoint.init(x: Float(point.x),
                                      y: Float(point.y),
                                      z: Float(mapController.userLocation.mapId))
let point = mapController.getNearestWaypoint(with: pointToJMapPoint ?? JMapPoint())
let x = Destination(name: "Some name", waypoint: point)
...
struct Destination {
    private (set) var name: String
    private (set) var waypoint: JMapWaypoint?

    init(destination: JMapDestination? = nil) {
        self.init(name: destination?.name ?? "Shared Location",
                  waypoint: destination?.waypoints?.first)
    }

    init(name: String, waypoint: JMapWaypoint?) {
        self.waypoint = waypoint
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

It is all up to you and depends on what you want.

Comment: One change I would make: Forward the initializer calls, all to one central init, so you have a central place to intercept initialization